# Meta data navigation filter on custom page?

Tags: list, managed-metadata, filter

I have a public facing website were i want our customers to be able to browse all our support documents using the Meta data navigation filter, but i dont want them to access the real document page. Is it possible to add the Navigation Filter to a Custom page in Sharepoin 2013?

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I am faced with exactly the same requirement, and have so far not been able to find an out-of-the-box solution.